# LaTeX Error: Environment keywords undefined

Tags: packages, keywords

I am using a template for a conference and everything is OK, except for the "Keywords", This is strange, it didn't occur to me before. Usually I don't use a specific package for keywords. and the code is as: `\begin{keywords} one, two, three, four \end{keywords}`. However, at this time the error is like below:

`LaTeX Error: Environment keywords undefined`

I would be so glad if you help me with this problem.
Mohammad.

Comment: How about `\keywords{one, two, three, four}`?

Comment: Nope, another error occurred with this one. the error was:
! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: none of the standard `article`, `report` `book` classes define a `keywords` command or environment. The AMS classes such as `amsart` define a `\keywords{...}` _command_ The class you are using doesn't define it. Do you think it should? Does the documentation for the conference say to use that syntax?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: There is nothing about this issue in "paper kit" in the conference webpage. However, I added \usepackage{amsart} as well, but it was not efficient!!!

Comment: The class of the article is \documentclass{article}

Comment: `\documentclass{article}` has no such command. Define `\newkommand\keywords[1]{}` in the preamble. Then your document will compile and later you can have a look for the correct documentclass which supports keywords.

Comment: you mean I put \newkommand\keywords[1]{} before \documentclass{article}? If yes, I did, but another error occurred.

Comment: Should you maybe be using the `elsarticle` document class, which does provide an environment called `keywords`.

Comment: @MohammadTofigi - use `\newcommand` rather than `\newkommand`...

Comment: But its not an Elsevier article!

Comment: @Mico - It compiled completely; however, now there is no keywords in the pdf.

Comment: i know of no *package* `amsart.sty`.  `amsart` is a document class: `\documentclass{amsart}`.  (it does have a different output style, and some differences in how the topmatter is handled, compared with `article`.)

Comment: @Mico- Oh sorry, it was commented, I removed the comment, they appeared, but instead of "index terms-one, two, three, four" its "ne, two, three, four" :D

Comment: you are looking for pdfkeywords, that is a complety other topic. I'll show it in an example

Comment: Nooo, in a paper, after abstract, there are keywords in this shape: "index terms- ...", but in your example, it appears inside the article.

Comment: @MohammadTofigi: Add `\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Index terms:}\quad #1}` *after* `\documentclass{article}` and then use `\keywords{one, two, three, four}` inside your document somewhere at/after the end of your abstract.

Comment: All this confusion would have been quickly cleared up if you had just provided a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  Providing such an example really makes life easier for *everyone*.

Comment: @jon- yeah you are right. In Herbert's example below you can find my problem. and you would need this package "spconf"

Comment: @Werner - it compiled and the "index term:" appeared there. However, it should be "index term-" bold and italic.

Comment: @MohammadTofigi: You don't *need* `spconf`...

Comment: @MohammadTofigi: Instead of `\textbf{..}` use `\textbf{\textit{Index terms-}}` in my command definition.

Comment: @Werner- WOW!!! Nice!! you did it! Thank you.  
Thank you all. Dear Werner-David Carlisle-Herbert-Mico-barbara beeton-jon.
the one I've intended, is as follows:
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index terms---}} #1}

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Define your own `\keywords` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index terms---}} #1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum\ldots
\end{abstract}
\keywords{one, two, three, four}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I use `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand` to accommodate the possibility that the document class you're using has defined `\keywords` already. `\providecommand` will only define it if not already defined.

Comment: Yeah, this one is also compiled successfully. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MohammadTofigi: If this answered your question, consider [accepting it as such](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ).

Comment: @Werner- I tried to do it, but since my reputation score is only 4, its not accepting my "The answer is useful". I had an account here, but I couldn't recover it. How can I do the "accepting it as such"?

Comment: @MohammadTofigi: You can click the tick mark (if you can't vote) which should mark this question as accepted (just below the vote buttons). [Voting on posts requires a certain amount of reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up). If you have multiple accounts that you've lost access to one, you should contact the StackExchange staff who can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 6):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf}

\begin{document}
foo
%
\begin{keywords}
One, two, three, four, five
\end{keywords}

\end{document}
```

my  files from the logfile:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  spconf.sty    
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
 ***********
```

Comment: Nooo, in a paper, after abstract, there are keywords in this shape: "index terms- ...", but in your example, it appears inside the article.

Comment: Again: then it is another document class!

Comment: but in the template the class is article. you can find the templates in this link:
http://www.icassp2014.org/PaperKit.html#Templates

Comment: see my edited answer. You need the package spconf, available on that site

Comment: yes I have it. even with that package, and with your edited answer, the same error occurs.
LaTeX Error: Environment keywords undefined

Comment: Then you do not saved the file in a correct place. For a first try put spconf.sty in the _same_ directory as the example doc

Comment: @Herbert- I did it, again the same!!!!

Comment: put `\listfiles` as first line in the document and then run it with `pdflatex` and then compare the file list which is at the end of the logfile.

Comment: @Werner- WOW!!! Nice!! you did it! Thank you. Thank you all. Dear Werner-David Carlisle-Herbert-Mico-barbara beeton-jon. the one I've intended, is as follows: \newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Index terms---}} #1}

Comment: @Herbert- without using the solution of Werner, it is stopping with the error and I cannot get the logfile.

Comment: This answer works as expected, if [`spconf.sty`](http://www.icassp2014.org/PaperFormat/spconf.sty) is appropriately used/placed. In general, see [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://goo.gl/ByVnz)