# How do I put keywords into abstract in elsarticle?

Tags: elsarticle, keywords

I am really new to LaTeX. I am preparing a journal article in Tex Studio. I downloaded TexLive as well and am using it. Problem is `\begin{keywords)` returns `unrecognized command`.

```
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
\end{keywords}
\end{frontmatter}
\maketitle
\date{today}
\newpage
```

How do I go about sorting this out? Thanks.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Environment `keywords` undefined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137291/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Looks like the OP targets a solution for `elsarticle` specifically.

Answer (score 17):

You can proceed using the `keyword` (not `keywords`) environment:

```
\documentclass[5p,number,preprint,times]{elsarticle}
% include here any package you may need
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
My wonderful abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}Something \sep%
    Something else
\end{keyword}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{The title of my beautiful article}

\author[unilu]{My name\corref{cor1}}
\ead{my.name@tex.sx}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: (+111) 11 11 11.}
\address[myuni]{University of Somewhere}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\end{frontmatter}


% == == == == == == == == == == == == == == ==
% Introduction
% == == == == == == == == == == == == == == ==
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! Am grateful. I did this by going to the macros menu where I created and saved the `keyword` environment macros (saved as "elskeyword" in my case). 
The rest was handled by command below

```
\let\elskeyword\keyword
\let\endelskeyword\endkeyword
\usepackage{program}
...
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title of my report}
\begin{elskeyword}
  keyword1 \sep keyword2 \sep keyword3 \sep keyword4
\end{elskeyword}
\end{frontmatter}
```

Am thankful to Stefan Kottwitz for this answer to a similar question here.....[program package ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69137/program-package-extra-or-forgotten-endgroup)

Comment: in the probable case that you preparing a journal submission, you should consult the author guidelines of the journal. if i remember correctly my experience with elsevier journals was that you are supposed to provide a separate list of keywords